# why ctags -R . don't generate index for source code in subdirectories?

Tags: linux, vim, indexing, editor, ctags

current directory:

```
[mirror@home libevent]$ ls
arc4random.c            bufferevent_sock.c     epoll.c                event_tagging.c      evutil.c           l                        Makefile.am         strlcpy-internal.h
autogen.sh              buffer_iocp.c          epoll_sub.c            evmap.c              evutil_rand.c      libevent_openssl.pc.in   Makefile.nmake      test
b                       changelist-internal.h  evbuffer-internal.h    evmap-internal.h     evutil_time.c      libevent.pc.in           minheap-internal.h  time-internal.h
buffer.c                ChangeLog              evconfig-private.h.in  evport.c             ht-internal.h      libevent_pthreads.pc.in  mm-internal.h       util-internal.h
bufferevent_async.c     ChangeLog-1.4          evdns.3                evrpc.c              http.c             LICENSE                  poll.c              whatsnew-2.0.txt
bufferevent.c           ChangeLog-2.0          evdns.c                evrpc-internal.h     http-internal.h    listener.c               ratelim-internal.h  whatsnew-2.1.txt
bufferevent_filter.c    compat                 event.3                evsignal-internal.h  include            log.c                    README              WIN32-Code
bufferevent-internal.h  configure.in           event.c                evthread.c           iocp-internal.h    log-internal.h           sample              win32select.c
bufferevent_openssl.c   defer-internal.h       event-internal.h       evthread-internal.h  ipv6-internal.h    m4                       select.c
bufferevent_pair.c      devpoll.c              event_iocp.c           evthread_pthread.c   kqueue.c           make_epoll_table.py      signal.c
bufferevent_ratelim.c   Doxyfile               event_rpcgen.py        evthread_win32.c     kqueue-internal.h  make-event-config.sed    strlcpy.c
```

there some files in test directory:

```
[mirror@home libevent]$ ls test/
bench.c              Makefile.am            regress_dns.c   regress_listener.c  regress_ssl.c        regress_zlib.c     test-fdleak.c    test-time.c      tinytest_local.h
bench_cascade.c      Makefile.nmake         regress_et.c    regress_main.c      regress_testutils.c  rpcgen_wrapper.sh  test-init.c      test-weof.c      tinytest_macros.h
bench_http.c         regress_buffer.c       regress.h       regress_minheap.c   regress_testutils.h  test-changelist.c  test-ratelim.c   tinytest.c
bench_httpclient.c   regress_bufferevent.c  regress_http.c  regress.rpc         regress_thread.c     test-dumpevents.c  test-ratelim.sh  tinytest_demo.c
check-dumpevents.py  regress.c              regress_iocp.c  regress_rpc.c       regress_util.c       test-eof.c         test.sh
```

**there are lots of file which have main() function in test directory**:

```
[mirror@home libevent]$ find test/ -regex .*.c -exec grep main {} +
test/regress.c:struct testcase_t main_testcases[] = {
test/test-weof.c:main(int argc, char **argv)
test/regress_dns.c:/* FIXME: We should move this to regress_main.c if anything else needs it.*/
test/regress_buffer.c:  size_t remaining;
test/regress_buffer.c:  remaining = v[0].iov_len - 512;
test/regress_buffer.c:  tt_int_op(remaining, ==, v[0].iov_len);
test/regress_buffer.c:  remaining -= 8;
test/regress_buffer.c:  n = evbuffer_reserve_space(buf, remaining+64, v, 2);
test/regress_buffer.c:  tt_int_op(remaining, ==, v[0].iov_len);
test/regress_buffer.c:  remaining -= 1;
test/regress_buffer.c:  n = evbuffer_reserve_space(buf, remaining+64, v, 2);
test/regress_buffer.c:  tt_int_op(remaining, ==, v[0].iov_len);
test/regress_buffer.c:  /* Drain some of the remaining chunk, then add it to another buffer */
test/regress_main.c:    { "main/", main_testcases },
test/regress_main.c:main(int argc, const char **argv)
test/regress_main.c:    if (tinytest_main(argc,argv,testgroups))
test/tinytest.c:static int in_tinytest_main = 0; /**< true if we're in tinytest_main().*/
test/tinytest.c:        if (!in_tinytest_main) {
test/tinytest.c:                       " called from within tinytest_main.\n");
test/tinytest.c:tinytest_main(int c, const char **v, struct testgroup_t *groups)
test/tinytest.c:        ++in_tinytest_main;
test/tinytest.c:        --in_tinytest_main;
test/test-eof.c:main(int argc, char **argv)
test/test-ratelim.c:main(int argc, char **argv)
test/tinytest_demo.c:main(int c, const char **v)
test/tinytest_demo.c:   /* Finally, just call tinytest_main().  It lets you specify verbose
test/tinytest_demo.c:   return tinytest_main(c, v, groups);
test/test-time.c:main(int argc, char **argv)
test/bench_cascade.c:main(int argc, char **argv)
test/test-dumpevents.c:   remain in the future.
test/test-dumpevents.c:main(int argc, char **argv)
test/test-changelist.c:main(int argc, char **argv)
test/test-init.c:main(int argc, char **argv)
test/test-fdleak.c:main(int argc, char **argv)
test/bench_http.c:main(int argc, char **argv)
test/bench.c:main(int argc, char **argv)
test/bench_httpclient.c:main(int argc, char **argv)
```

but after i using:

```
ctags -R .
```

open vim, then

```
:tag main
:g ]
```

the status bar just shows:

```
E433: No tags file
E426: tag not found: main
```

what's wrong? **the tags file is already loaded, why No tags file?** it is confusing...

seems the index generated by ctags have include these files which include main function:

```
3643 main    sample/dns-example.c    /^main(int c, char **v) {$/;"   f
3644 main    sample/event-read-fifo.c        /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3645 main    sample/hello-world.c    /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3646 main    sample/http-server.c    /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3647 main    sample/le-proxy.c       /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3648 main    sample/signal-test.c    /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3649 main    sample/time-test.c      /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3650 main    test/bench.c    /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3651 main    test/bench_cascade.c    /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3652 main    test/bench_http.c       /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3653 main    test/bench_httpclient.c /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3654 main    test/regress_main.c     /^main(int argc, const char **argv)$/;" f
3655 main    test/test-changelist.c  /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3656 main    test/test-dumpevents.c  /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3657 main    test/test-eof.c /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3658 main    test/test-fdleak.c      /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3659 main    test/test-init.c        /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3660 main    test/test-ratelim.c     /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3661 main    test/test-time.c        /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3662 main    test/test-weof.c        /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"       f
3663 main    test/tinytest_demo.c    /^main(int c, const char **v)$/;"       f
3664 main_callback   sample/dns-example.c    /^main_callback(int result, char type, int count, int ttl,$/;"  f       file:
3665 main_testcases  test/regress.c  /^struct testcase_t main_testcases[] = {$/;"    v       typeref:struct:testcase_t
```

but why tag main, g ] can not locate the list of files which contain main function?

**romainl's solution works for :tag name even when autochdir is enabled**

i have run :set tags=./tags,tags, it works even when current dir is changed to others since autochdir is enabled, but g ] may not work sometimes, why?

but g ] not works sometimes:

the error info is **E257: cstag: tag not found**

**Edit 2**: content of .vimrc

```
cat ~/.vimrc
set autoindent
colorscheme desert
set number
```

Comment: What does `:set tags` and `:pwd` print when you run Vim?

Comment: @xaizek i have set autochdir, so pwd may change when i open files

Comment: Anyway, could you add output of those commands? For me `autochdir` doesn't work in some cases.

Comment: @xaizek the output is E433: No tags file
E426: tag not found: main

Comment: Did you run `:set tags` and `:pwd`? I don't think they can print something like that.

Comment: I'm tired of managing ctags by hand, and I wrote plugin Indexer for that: http://goo.gl/IEmtZ . It provides painless automatic tags generation for the whole project(s) and keeps tags up-to-date. You might want to check this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `E433` error means that Vim didn't find your `tags` file so, no, **the tags file is not already loaded.**

Typing `:set tags` should output something like:

```
./tags,tags
```

That's the default value and it means "look for a `tags` file located in the directory of the current file *then* in the current directory".

Because you have `set autochdir`, it may happen that you end up in a directory without a `tags` file. In `test`, for example.

To make sure that Vim finds your `tags` file, you should use something like:

```
set tags=./tags,tags;$HOME
```

It means "look for a `tags` file located in the directory of the current file *then* in the current directory *then* in any parent directory up to `$HOME`".

***edit***

Well, the setting above has worked as expected for me for a long while. But here is the little experiment I just did (with `set autochdir`, of course):

1. I'm in `~/workspace/accordion/` that contains only one file, `accordion.js`.
2. I do `$ ctags -R .`: `~/workspace/accordion/tags` is created.
3. I do `$ mkdir -p aa/bb/cc/dd/ee/ff`.
4. I do `$ vim aa/bb/cc/dd/ee/ff/test.js`.
5. In Vim, I do `:tag *mini` which jumps to the declaration of the `mini()` method, member of the `Accordion()` constructor located in `~/workspace/accordion/accordion.js`, *as expected*.

Because I've got `set tags=./tags,tags;$HOME` in my `~/.vimrc` Vim correctly crawled from dir to dir until it reached `~/worspace/accordion/tags`. Even if I was quite deep in an unrealistically deep file tree.

```
Is there an accordion/aa/bb/cc/dd/ee/ff/tags ? no, let's go up…
Is there an accordion/aa/bb/cc/dd/ee/tags ? no, let's go up…
Is there an accordion/aa/bb/cc/dd/tags ? no, let's go up…
Is there an accordion/aa/bb/cc/tags ? no, let's go up…
Is there an accordion/aa/bb/tags ? no, let's go up…
Is there an accordion/aa/tags ? no, let's go up…
Is there an accordion/tags ? yes! let's scan it!
```

As another commenter asked you repeatedly without success, what is the output of `:pwd` when you are in the subdirectory? Here is another request: what is the output of `:call tagfiles()`?

Comment: but autochdir is enabled, so  once i jump to subdirectories other than current directory, tags file is not in my current directory then... does it matters? so how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Did you read my answer? With `set tags=./tags,tags;$HOME` your `tags` file will be found even if it's in a parent directory.

Comment: yes, i have read your answer, but my tags is not in fixed diretory, it is just in the project's directory

Comment: It doesn't matter. With this setting you can have your `tags` file at the root of your project dir, say `/a/` and be in `/a/` or `/a/b/c/` or `/a/q/r/s/`, Vim will look up and up for a `tags` file until it finds one (or none: `E433`). In the last example, Vim will look for `/a/q/r/s/tags`, then `/a/q/r/tags`, then `/a/q/tags`, then `/a/tags`, bingo!

Comment: in fact, i only searchs /a/, if i set autochdir, once i am in /a/b/c :tag name will just return E433 error, why?

Comment: Did you add that line (or a variant that suits your directory structure) to your `~/.vimrc` or not? See my edit for a real life example.

Comment: your method works for :tag main, but g ] not works sometimes:
the error info is E257: cstag: tag not found (i have add details in my question)

Comment: What language do you work with? `<C-]>` and `g]` work only if the word under the cursor is exactly the same as in the `tags` file. In my example, the word under the cursor would be `mini` but Vim won't find the definition because it's indexed as `Accordion.mini()`.

Comment: for example :tag main have two hits, one .c and the other .py, if i choose to jump to .c, then g ] work, but if i jump to .py, g ], failed with E257: cstag: tag not found,why?

Comment: Maybe ctags is a little confused when dealing with multiple filetypes? Or with Python? Also try do do all that without involving `cscope`.

Comment: **You** told Vim to use both cscope and ctags by adding `:set cscopetag` somewhere in your `~/.vimrc`. Remove or comment out that line to ensure that `:tag` (and `g]` and `<C-]>`) is in fact `:tag` and not `:cstag`.

Comment: there is no cscope related settings in ~/.vimrc, if there is no cscope index files , then cscope will not work, right? but why E257: cstag: tag not found seems have something to do with cscope?

Comment: In normal operation, `:tag` is just `:tag` and you never see `cstag` anywhere. But when you do `:tag foo`, you get a `:cstag` message.  you appear to have `:tag` aliased to `:cstag` **and it only happens when you `set cscopetag`.** You could try `:help cscope` and `:help ctags`, a lot of what we are talking about is covered there.

Comment: yes, maybe i have runed set cscopetag, but once i quit vim, will that command still makes effect the next time i start to run vim?

Comment: No it won't. Check your vimrc or, better, post it somewhere so we can read it.

Comment: cat ~/.vimrc
set autoindent
colorscheme desert
set number

Comment: Why didn't you add the line in my answer?

Comment: Did you or did you not add `set tags=./tags,tags;$HOME` to your vimrc?

Comment: why it's ./tags,tags;$HOME, and not ./tags,tags,$HOME

Comment: The `,` is used to separate specific directories: Vim would look *only* into these directories. The `;` is used to tell vim to climb the file tree up to the given directory, `$HOME` in my setup. As I explained before, if you are working on `/home/username/a/aa/aaa/aaaa/file.py`, Vim will simply look for a `tags` file in `/home/username/a/aa/aaa/aaaa/`, then `/home/username/a/aa/aaa/`, then `/home/username/a/aa/`, then `/home/username/a/`, then `/home/username/`. **Adding this line is the only thing you need to do to solve your problem.** Did you try it or not?

Comment: @romainl Hey, I used your solution. Still I am getting the error: no tags found. Can you help me?

Comment: @crisron, you should post a question instead.